# Finding indices of string array1 in string array2

Tags: arrays, idl-programming-language

I have two string arrays:

```
A = ['i4x://C/2013/problem/b4ce36e6a5f745ddb061636fc86ed3cb', $
     'i4x://C/2013/problem/08b2360eea2a4a95930b073694f7b5b2', $
     'i4x://C/2013/problem/6f7493b64628424db6a46354179bd887']
```

And

```
B = ['i4x://C/2013/problem/02bfbcf3f8b94eed81f89573be253be3', $
'i4x://C/2013/problem/02cfda1e68174d3e89549e828b270339', $
'i4x://C/2013/problem/b4ce36e6a5f745ddb061636fc86ed3cb', $
'i4x://C/2013/problem/04683dc23ab14934ba9fc32a9ad25bfb', $
'i4x://C/2013/problem/08b2360eea2a4a95930b073694f7b5b2', $
'i4x://C/2013/problem/bad0517331d34336a29d9c5e898decf1', $
'i4x://C/2013/problem/6f7493b64628424db6a46354179bd887']
```

I'm trying to get all the indices of A in B,
using the following command line

```
k = where(strcmp(A, B),cnt)
print, k
```

But it doesn't work!
Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way to do this,

Just google match.pro or match2.pro